# Wicket adding a big Pdf as resource

Tags: java, pdf, wicket

In my app I display pdf's using a ByteArrayResource.
This was working fine untill I started working with bigger files. The conversion to ByteArray keeps giving me an out of memory error.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
        File myPdf=new File(thePath);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(myPdf);
        final byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)myPdf.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);
        fin.close();
        ResourceReference rr = new ResourceReference(dePdf.getName()) {

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            return new ByteArrayResource("Application/pdf", fileContent);

        }
        };
        if (rr.canBeRegistered()) {
            getApplication().getResourceReferenceRegistry().registerResourceReference(rr);
        }        

        return wmc;
```

**Is there a better way to display a big file?**

Comment: Is `myPDF` dynamically generated? If it isn't, you could use [`DownloadLink`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/DownloadLink.html) instead.

Comment: I want to display the file in a <object> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using ResourceStreamResource and FileResourceStream:

```
File myPdf=new File(thePath);
FileResourceStream frs = new FileResourceStream(myPdf);

ResourceStreamResource rsr = new ResourceStreamResource(frs);
rsr.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT);
rsr.setFileName(fileName);

//the same code for resource reference creation and registration
//...
```

Comment: Since I wanted it to be displayed inline I used ContentDisposition.INLINE .

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've read your comment about object tag just now.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure (never really used them myself) but a [ContextRelativeResource](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/ContextRelativeResource.html) may be an option. Perhaps something like:

```
final File myPdf=new File(thePath);
        ResourceReference rr = new ResourceReference(dePdf.getName()) {

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            // You'll need to adjust the path here to be relative to your context
            return new ContextRelativeResource(myPdf.getAbsolutePath());

        }
        };
        if (rr.canBeRegistered()) {
            getApplication().getResourceReferenceRegistry().registerResourceReference(rr);
        }
```